# Notification link takes me to the wrong chat room

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, notifications, global-inbox

A little while ago I recieved a message in my inbox notifying me of a reply to my post in **Tavern on the Meta**

It looked like this:

[image]

It should have taken me [here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1655528#1655528)

However when I click it, I get taken [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1655528?noredirect=1#1655528)

why?

Comment: It looks like the link points to `chat.stackexchange.com` instead of `chat.meta.stackoverflow.com` which is sending you to the wrong site entirely. I assume it used to work properly before and should be an easy fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was fixed in a build that went out a few minutes ago.  It's on a per-message basis, so future messages won't have the icon or link issues.